# IP address / port is reacheable by one process but not by another

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10

We have a strange networking problem like this:
There is machine A with multiple network interfaces, one of them is 10.10.45.45/16. Connected is a Server S with ip:10.10.45.47 streaming data on port 9696. The other interfaces on machine A are 192.168.0.1, 192.168.1.1

The strange behaviour: we get data from S while connecting through a browser from machine A. We have another application (written in c) running stand alone also on machine A which cannot connect to 10.10.45.47:9696. This setup and the application is standard and works in other similar setups correctly. Tealnet is also able to connect.

Any thoughts on that? Could it be that c has weird behaviour selecting a proper interface?

Comment: Are you getting data through the web browser on port 9696, or on port 80? Also it's strange that your other interfaces are 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.1.1, are you using the server as a gateway / router as well?

Comment: Evidently the application is not accessing S in the same way as the browser, but only you can find out why.

Comment: the machine is not a gateway between the interfaces. Why are the other interfaces strange (192.168.0.1, 192.168.1.1)? The browser uses also port 9696

Comment: You'll need to provide more information like netstat -rn.  Is the other program something you wrote or a specific package ?  It's possible that your issue is that your second program is binding to a specific interface and your system can't route based on the setup.  As @harrymc said, you'll need to dig underneath it.